# newbie asking suggestion for gem structure

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I plan to write a gem that create a zip file by download from a link or get from filesystem  or from a string and upload to s3. Is it a good idea I hijack the Zip module from rubyzip?

```
Zip::Voidzip.upload! do |zip|
  zip.add "http://example.com/example.png", :as => "image/zzz.png"
  zip.add "asdasdasdads"
  zip.add "asd/asd.png"
end
```

Since the code most probabily will be like this.

```
module Zip
  class Voidzip
    def initialize zipname
      t = Tempfile.new(zipname)
      ZipOutputStream.open(t.path) do |zos|

      end
    end
  end
end
```

Any suggestion for newbie that want to contribute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best practice is to name your gem `voidzip`.

If you are intending your gem to be a **plugin** for `zip`, and if `zip` actually supports a plugin architecture, then practice would be to name your gem `zip-voidzip` (but I don't think that's the case here).

Your module/namespace structure should mirror your gem's name.

If your gem is named `voidzip`, then I expect all of your code to be within `Voidzip` and I expect to be able to `require "voidzip"`.

If your gem is named `zip-voidzip`, then I expect all of your code to be within `Zip::Voidzip` and I expect to be able to `require "zip-voidzip"` or `require "zip/voidzip"` at my choice.

Answer (score 1):

*// Off topic, what the OP's trying to do isn't monkeypatching per-se (see @Beerlington's comment)*

I generally try to stay away from monkey-patching, unless I cannot do otherwise. It's always painful to debug something and find out that a gem creator thought it was a good idea to override functionality you're depending on.

But don't trust me, [trust him](http://avdi.org/devblog/2008/02/23/why-monkeypatching-is-destroying-ruby/), he's much more experienced that I am.

*// Off topic end*

You could try to be a little creative and come up with a nice gem name :-) .

Couldn't you just go with the `Voidzip` name, without nesting it into `Zip`?

Comment: This is arguably not monkey patching since it isn't overriding or modifying existing functionality and just adding a new class to an existing module.

Comment: @Beerlington Ah, thanks, I thought the the `Voidzip` class already existed. I updated my answer